# Create certificate having CA-cert and keys with long Serial using C#

Tags: c#, openssl, certificate, x509, csr

Please advice or share a sample code to create X509 certificate with serial like 123746392047474849, from existing CA certificate with private key and CSR request.
I tried to use OpenSSL.Net, but it only accepts "int" serials.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) library which supports [BigIntegers](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/math/BigInteger.cs) and is fully written in C#.

Comment: No, there is some progress. Version 1.8.0 beta2 was announced in march 2014. If you look at [this page](http://downloads.bouncycastle.org/betas/) there is v1.8.0 beta3 now available. Subscribe to the mailing list to get all the news. It seems they do not update the web page very often.